# How do I setup three monitors in XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce

I have a laptop with an intel chip, and I'd like to set up three monitors in Xfce.
One of them would be my laptop and then two monitors. I have one HDMI and one type C port

Comment: What is the problem that you are experiencing?  Does your iGPU support the native display +3? (Most do not)

Comment: You've provided no release details, and if using a LTS release which kernel stack you've chosen to use (LTS releases offer two stacks; the default stack chosen by the Xubuntu media used for installation).  Most configuration is done purely with Xfce, however what options you have available may differ with what *unstated* kernel stack you are using, plus what display drivers you're using (eg. *I have a box here which recently changed behavior because I switched from open-source to closed-source proprietary kernel modules*). We know very little about your software stack currently.